# Why is Lotus WCM generating references with myconnect to anonymous users?

Tags: websphere, portal, lotus, wcm

Hi we've been getting an issue in which WCM references are being generated 
towards protected content for anonymous/unauthenticated users. In WCM this 
basically means that the links have a "/myconnect" (protected) context instead
of a "/connect" (unprotected) context in their URL.

Now WAS has a functionality in which if a user generates a request towards a
protected resource while being unauthenticated WAS places the URL to that 
resource in a cookie called WASReqURL, and when the user authenticates it 
redirects the user to that URL. In my case our users are getting redirected 
to an image resource or a file resource, etc. This changes depending what is
the last requested protected item and what's in the cache, etc.

Now I've checked permissions on the libraries, sites, content items, components, 
etc, but that still doesn't help. And the worst thing is that this issue is 
intermittent almost as if it was tied to some sort of performance issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lotus WCM really does that when it thinks the anonymous user does not have enough access rights. If you are absolutely sure that your access rights are properly defined, congratulations. You have found something worth opening PMR. Attach the PUMA mustgather to it.

Comment: Sorry sorry for my late response and thank you for your help. I already suggested them to create a PMR. I'll be sure to post back my findings.